# get Integer value from EditText Android

Tags: java, android, class, android-edittext, integer

This is my `activity.xml`

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/inputnumber"
 android:inputType="number" />
```

this is `mainactivity.java` :

```
EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.Id.inputnumber) ;
```

the question is how can I get the integer value from this field as an integer and use it for example in a custom class I made like this to add 1 to the value of this input field?

my customclass.java

```
public static int addone(int a) 
{
  int b = a+1;
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can achieve this as

```
int val = Integer.parseInt( num.getText().toString() );
```

and than pass `val` to the method `addone(val);`

Comment: when parsing Int make sure the format of the string by eight of 2 ways. Either you set the input format as Integer only or do a try catch while parsing the string.

Comment: thanks about the solution but I used that already and when I start my app and it reaches to this point it would be "unfortunately the app stopped working..."

Comment: @user4030877 could you please post the whole source file?

Answer (score 1):

Get it beautiful

```
   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkEmptyFileds(txt_birey_adet, txt_limit)) {
                int girilenSayi = Integer.parseInt(txt_birey_adet.getText().toString());
                int limit = Integer.parseInt(txt_limit.getText().toString()); 
            } 
        }
    });


private boolean checkEmptyFileds(EditText txt_birey_adet, EditText txt_limit) {
    boolean onay = true;
    if (txt_birey_adet.getText().toString().equals("")) {
       // Util.getInstance(OzelHesap.this).bounceEffect3(txt_birey_adet);
        onay = false;
    } else if (txt_limit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        //Util.getInstance(OzelHesap.this).bounceEffect3(txt_limit);
        onay = false;
    }
    return onay;
}
```